# ObjectResult containing list of objects in ASP.NET MVC6 Web Api

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm getting to grips creating an API using MVC 6.  I have several simple response models for which I'm using an `ObjectResult` as follows:

```
[Route("api/foos")]
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetFoos()
    {
        return new ObjectResult(FooRepository.GetAll().Select(FooModel.From));
    }
}
```

And this works fine when `FooModel` is a simple model containing a few properties and even a list of simple types, like strings.

However, I am now trying to follow a similar pattern where `FooModel` contains a list of other objects within it, and I'd like to show the details of these nicely formatted in my JSON response, as an array of objects. However, with the following classes I get "No response recieved".

```
public class FooModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    public FooModel(Guid id, string name, List<Bar> bars)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Bars = bars;
    }
    internal static FooModel From(Foo foo)
    {
        return new FooModel(foo.Id, foo.Name, foo.Bars);
    }
}

public class BarModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BarModel(Guid id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
    internal static BarModel From(Bar bar)
    {
        return new BarModel(bar.Id, bar.Name);
    }
}
```

If I change the `List<Bar>` to a list of strings, the response displays a JSON array of strings nicely. How can I get my response to return the the list of inner object as an array of objects in my JSON response?

Comment: so what is the question exactly?

Comment: Sorry about that, wasn't quite finished!  Added the last paragraph which comprises the question.

Comment: `List<Bar>` should have already serialized to array of Bar objects...aren't you seeing that happening?

Comment: No - it simply returns "no response received".  With a array of simple data types, such as `string`, it serializes correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the effect I was looking for, but I'm not sure exactly why this works - if anyone knows why, please share!  I think the reason `List<Bar>` does not serialize to an array of `Bar` objects is because `Bar` is in a different project (as it is part of a deeper (domain) layer of my solution).  It works when I change the `FooModel` to reference a list of `BarModel` and populate it by changing `FooModel` to populate this list with the static `BarModel.From` method as follows:

```
public class FooModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<BarModel> Bars { get; set; }
    public FooModel(Guid id, string name, List<Bar> bars)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Bars = bars.Select(BarModel.From).ToList();
    }
    internal static FooModel From(Foo foo)
    {
        return new FooModel(foo.Id, foo.Name, foo.Bars);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its possible that the `Bar` type is unable to be serialized by the formatter (for exmaple, due to reference loops)...try this: put the middleware mentioned in the link here 'before' Mvc and while in debug mode check what exception you see with having `Bar` type: hmm...its possible there is some exception being thrown when serializing `Bar` type...https://gist.github.com/kichalla/cf1d09d8e2f0a9da4b03

Answer (score 0):

If your classes look like this common setup when using EntityFramework CodeFirst approach

```
public class Foo
{
    ...
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars {get;set;}
    ...
}

public class Bar
{
    ...
    public int FooId {get;set;}
    public Foo Foo {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Foo cannot be serialized due to reference loops.
For an API to return correctly serialized JSON you have to add the `[JsonIgnore]` Attribute for the Foo-Property in the Bar-class:

```
public class Bar
{
    ...
    public int FooId {get;set;}

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Foo Foo {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

This is assuming you are using NewtonsoftJson as serializer.

Thanks to @KiranChalla for the comment in @Ivans answer.  This pointed me to the right direction.